# How can I print the binary code of a file in c?

Tags: c

So I want to make a checksum on windows but first I need to get one string with the information of the file in binary but my code show only the information in other formats, can anyone help me get this to show this information only with 0 and 1?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct{
    char linha[1024];
}linha;



int main() {
    linha linha1;
    char temp[1024];
    FILE *arquivo;
    if((arquivo = fopen("C:\\62-Q2.mp3","rb"))==NULL){
        printf("Erro ao abrir o arquivo.");
        exit(1);
    }
    fseek(arquivo, sizeof(linha), SEEK_SET);
    while(!feof(arquivo)) {
        fread(&linha1,sizeof(linha),1,arquivo);
        strcpy(temp, linha1.linha);
        printf("%u\n", temp);
    }
    fclose(arquivo);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Do you want to print it in binary format?

Comment: Yes, to be more clear I want the binary information from the file but when I try to print to see if I'm getting it the result is not binary.

Answer (score 1):

```
strcpy(temp, linha1.linha);
```

this line makes no sense at all as you do not read text file.

```
while(!feof(arquivo))
```

This is always wrong.

To dump file as bytes in bin:

```
void printByteAsBin(unsigned char ch)
{
    unsigned char mask = 1 << (CHAR_BIT - 1);
    for(; mask; mask >>= 1) printf("%c", (ch & mask) ? '1' : '0');
}
void dumpBin(FILE *fi, int linelen)
{
    int ch = fgetc(fi);
    int linepos = 0;
    char str[linelen + 1];
    while(ch != EOF)
    {
        printByteAsBin(ch);
        str[linepos] = (isalpha(ch) || ch == ' ') ? ch : '.';
        if(++linepos < linelen) printf(" ");
        else {str[linepos] = 0; printf(" %s\n", str); linepos = 0;}
        ch = fgetc(fi);
    }
    if(ch == EOF && linepos != linelen )
    {
        for(int x = 0; x < (linelen - linepos) * 9; x++, printf(" "));
        str[linepos] = 0;
        printf("%s\n", str);
    }
}
```

You should add some error and parameter checking.

Demo:
https://godbolt.org/z/5nqeG3fE8

```
01001000 01100101 01101100 01101100 01101111 00100000 Hello 
01010111 01101111 01110010 01101100 01100100 00001010 World.
```

Comment: what is the linelen that you receive as a argument?

Comment: @Adriel the number of bytes that are printed per line.

Comment: Thanks!!Can you comment the code, some parts of it I don't recognize like the ? and why you say that ch is a int but the function receive it as a char.